# IIF Null Blank If not Run the contents

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a search query that runs at the push of a button and searches a subforms contents. It has 5 course options on it, all of which always have a default value of NULL unless a course is selected. THis makes it more user friendly. I am trying to setup the search code to clear the combo box if it is null, and leave it alone if it is not. I am trying the below code and it is not working:

```
Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![cboDevelopment1] & "*" And iif([Forms]![frmCDData]![cboDevelopment1],= NULL, "", = [Forms]![frmCDData]![cboDevelopment1])
```

I get the error saying the above code has the wrong number of arguments. Are there any alternate ideas or ways to fix the above code to work?

The code looks like this on its own without the IIF

```
Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![cboDevelopment1] & "*"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want

```
WHERE Table1.AText=[Forms]![frmCDData]![cboDevelopment1]
   OR table1.AText = 
     IIf(Not IsNull([frmCDData]![cboDevelopment2]),[frmCDData]![cboDevelopment1],"")
```

From what you say, you are running a query. You have combos, so the text should be exact, you do not need Like.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an extra comma before = NULL
try this,

```
Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![cboDevelopment1] & "*" And iif([Forms]![frmCDData]![cboDevelopment1]= NULL, "", [Forms]![frmCDData]![cboDevelopment1])
```

Comment: I made all the changes but it is still returning no values, and with the records I have in there now it should be returning 1. And it is not clearing the records either

Comment: Can you post the full snippet of code?  It may help me get a better understanding.

Comment: The full snippet is huge. I think it would be too big to go through.

Answer (score 0):

In this portion `iif([Forms]![frmCDData]![cboDevelopment1],= NULL` you have an extra comma between you field value and `=null`.  This is causing your statement to think it is receiving 4 parameters instead of 3.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is an extra comma as the others have pointed out, there are a couple additional problems.  You need quotes around the word "Null" because it's a string.  Also, you don't want the `=` in the last parameter.

```
IIf([Forms].[frmCDData].[cboDevelopment1]="Null","",[Forms].[frmCDData].[cboDevelopment1])
```

Comment: The actual text value of the combo box is null, which is what I am trying to clear. Only if it is the null value.

Comment: You mean the actual word "null"?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean

Comment: That seems like a bad idea.  I think the right way to do that would have them be actually null, not the word "Null".  But anyway, I updated my answer to fit your scenario.

Comment: I am open for suggested changes if you have any?

Comment: It's just a little confusing using the word "Null".  I would have it be null (i.e. no value at all) or use a different phrase like "No course selected" or something like that.